# Bisection method complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, approximation

Can the bisection method of root finding be used to find the **complex roots** of a polynomial, i.e, **complex** values of $x$ such that $f\left(x\right)\:=\:0$?

In the bisection method we arbitrarily choose two starting points with opposite signs and then see if the value of the function at the midpoint of these two points is a root. If it is, we stop, if it is not we halve the interval depending on which side of the interval gives us a closer result.

Link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

My gut feeling is to say that it can't but I am not entirely sure how to justify it.

I know Newton's method can but am not sure about this one.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: There are no signs in complex numbers...and there are no intervals, either. It's like working with the plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ for that matter

Comment: @DonAntonio I see. So because of this, the bisection can't be used to find complex roots?

Comment: There is a winding number variation on the bisection method. [Here](https://youtu.be/b7FxPsqfkOY) is 3blue1brown's video on the subject. I don't know to what degree it's actually usable in practice, though. (This winding number idea is the core of my favourite proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

If $f(z) = 0$ can be represented as

$$
\cases{
f_r(x,y) = 0\\
f_i(x,y) = 0
}
$$

we can use a [bintree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to determine into a plane region the **trace** of $f_r=0, f_i=0$ and then we will have within a required precision the set of points which verify the equation. The binthree for $\mathbb{R}^2$ or octree for $\mathbb{R}^3
$ can be processed recursively in a fashion very akin to the binary search process to $\mathbb{R}$ problems